# How do I plot Troels-Smith lithological symbols in R?

Tags: sedimentology

I'm trying to plot lithological data using the Troels-Smith scheme. I have tried psimpoll but as I only have lithological data I cannot create a main input file which is required. I also do not have access to the plotting graphics in Tilia. All I want to create is a clean lithological diagram. 
Is there a package in R or another opensource/free tool for getting such plots that anyone might be aware of?